# Knockoutjs, SPA, MVC 4 how to passing data from Knockoutjs to Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, singlepage, knockout-2.0

i'm working with knockoutjs and MVC and i really don't know how to pass data from Knockoutjs to Controller.
I try to use

```
    self.NextButton = function () {
        $.post("/User/MyAction', self.uUserSet);
    }
```

but not work.
Please show me how to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get data back to an MVC controller from Knockout.

A good post demonstrating this is [MVC jQuery submit form (without page refresh) from JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720020/mvc-jquery-submit-form-without-page-refresh-from-javascript-function).

Steve Sanderson did a presentation at TechDays in the Netherlands in February where he demonstrated passing data from Knockout to MVC (or actually to the new WebAPI) using the renamed RIA/JS library (now Upshot.js). Upshot does have some challenges but it provides a good solution. It is well worth investigating.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159

[Here is a question and answer I posted regarding some of the challenges of using Upshot. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711637/what-would-make-entity-framework-upshot-believe-my-object-graph-contains-cycl]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711637/what-would-make-entity-framework-upshot-believe-my-object-graph-contains-cycl)

You can also find information (and examples) on the main Knockout website (http://knockoutjs.com/), and on Ryan Niemeyer's blog (http://www.knockmeout.net/).

You may also want to take a look JSON.NET. http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx